# Как сохранять картинку, отправленную телеграм ботом в аккаунт пользователя?

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, изображения

Всем добрый день!
Пишу телеграм-бота на Python c библиотекой Telebot и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Бот отправляет рандомную картинку пользователю из хранилища (на данный момент это просто папка на компьютере) на определенный запрос (нажатие кнопки).
И необходимо, чтоб картинка (и последующие полученные им), полученная пользователем от бота, сохранялась в аккаунте пользователя в данном боте (регистрация пользователя происходит через базу данных sql), и чтоб пользователь при выборе определённой команды (условно "Мои картинки"), мог посмотреть все те картинки, который он получил от бота?
Собственно, в этом и заключается сложность, ибо я не знаю как это реализовать
Сам я новичок в программировании, поэтому опыта и знаний у меня не очень много, могу просто не знать/понимать что-то

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Если все картинки уже у вас на сервере, значит вы можете в базе данных просто хранить имена этих файлов. Этого уже будет достаточно, чтобы реализовать все вышеперечисленные функции.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз загружать изображение в телеграм нежелательно. Рекомендованным способом передачи фото является отправка по `file_id`.
В вашем случае, я думаю, будет достаточно следующего:
Создаем в БД 2 таблицы: список изображений и кому что отправили

```
CREATE TABLE `pics` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` bigint NOT NULL,
  `file_unique_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

и вторая:

```
CREATE TABLE `rates` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` bigint NOT NULL,
  `file_unique_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

)
Отправили изображение по `file_id` из первой таблицы? Записали во вторую `id` - кому отправили и `file_unique_id` - что отправили

Это схема в общем случае